# Empty Sequence in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I recently faced an interview question related to LINQ.

What is the use of empty sequence?.He asked "if i suppose to ask you to use the one,where do you fit it?"

```
     public static IEnumerable<TResult> Empty<TResult>()
     {
        yield break;
     }
```

I did not answer it.Help is appreciated.

Comment: How is empty sequence formed?  How do you fit it?

Comment: +1 for a good question in my opinion.

Comment: @Stan I have to say you a lot  of thanks for clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this when you want to quickly create an `IEnumerable<T>` this way you don't have to create a reference to a new `List<T>` and take advantage of the **yield** keyword.

```
List<string[]> namesList =
    new List<string[]> { names1, names2, names3 };

// Only include arrays that have four or more elements
IEnumerable<string> allNames =
    namesList.Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<string>(),
    (current, next) => next.Length > 3 ? current.Union(next) : current);
```

Note the use of **Union** because it is not a **List** you can not call **Add** method, but you could call **Union** on an `IEnumerable`

Comment: You might get better performance using Concat instead of Union, unless you really need to exclude duplicates.

Comment: The fastest way of all to join a bunch of lists like that using LINQ is namesList.SelectMany(list => list.Length>4 ? list : Enumerable.Empty<string>()).Distinct().  Doing it with Aggregate and Union is extremely inefficient.  Aggregate and Concat is better but is still O(Nsquared) and O(N) space.  SelectMany/Distinct is O(N) and O(1) space (just 3 objects are created).

Answer (score 4):

If you had a loop that aggregated together different sets into a result set you can use it to initialize your result set variable and loop/accumulate. For example:

```
IEnumerable<string> results = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

for(....)
{
    IEnumerable<string> subset = GetSomeSubset(...);

    results = results.Union(subset);
}
```

Without Empty you'd have to have written a null check into your loop logic:

```
IEnumerable<string> results = null;

for(....)
{
    IEnumerable<string> subset = GetSomeSubset(...);

    if(results == null)
    {
        results = subset;
    }
    else
    {
        results = results.Union(subset);
    }
}
```

It doesn't just have to be a loop scenario and it doesn't have to be Union (could be any aggregate function), but that's one of the more common examples.

Comment: Good answer to the question posed.  Readers should note that my performance comment above also applies to this code. Using Union this way is O(Nsquared) because it creates a Set for each union and fills it with all strings so far. Well I guess that's technically O(NM). The point it that it is very slow and SelectMany/Distinct is much better for this kind of scenario.